# Copy OLEObject from Excel to a newly created Powerpoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint, ole

I'm struggling to get the API usage correct, even after hours of searching.

Basically, I want to do the following from my Excel file.

1) Create a new Powerpoint presentation and slide. [DONE]

2) Copy OLEObject from the Excel file into the Powerpoint slide.

What I have done so far for the no. 2 is

```
Dim s As Shapes
For Each Obj in Worksheets("TEMPLATE").OLEObjects
  'Copy OLEObjects from Excel to Powerpoint slide
  Set s = pptSlide.Shapes.AddOLEObject '( ... ?? ... )
Next Obj
```

Please help me on how to copy the OLEObjects from the Excel file into the Powerpoint slide.

Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply copy and paste the OBJObjects?

```
For Each Obj in Worksheets("TEMPLATE").OLEObjects
  'Copy OLEObjects from Excel to Powerpoint slide
  Obj.Copy()
  pptSlide.Shapes.Paste()
Next Obj
```

EDIT FOR COMMENT

The paste method should return a ShapeRange object.  You can set the [top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251277%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and left properties of the first shape in your returned ShapeRange.  I didn't test this (and I don't use VB.NET) but it should be something like this:

```
Dim sr as ShapeRange
Dim sh as Shape

Set sr = pptSlide.Shapes.Paste()
Set sh = sr.Item(1)
sh.Left = 10
sh.Top = 10
```

Comment: Sounds like a good suggestion. Any idea how to position it at certain x,y ?